# custom function Roles of users not woking, nested query, prisma graphql

Tags: javascript, nested, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

This function isn't working properly

```
function getRolesOfUser(parent, args, context, info) {    

    return context.prisma.userHasRoles({user:args.user});
}
```

I have tried changing the paremeter in the query

```
{where: {user:user}}
{['User.id']:args.user}
```

This is the schema

```
type Query {
  getRolesOfUser(user: String): [UserHasRole]
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  roles: [UserHasRole]
}
type Role {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
type UserHasRole {
  id: ID!
  role: Role!
  user: User!
}
```

Error message:

```
Could not find argument user for type UserHasRole",
```

Expected to receive the list of roles related to a certain user

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following code

```js
function getRolesOfUser(parent, args, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.userHasRoles({ where: { user: { id: args.user.id } } })
}
```

In your schema, `user` is a field of `UserHasRole`. First select the `user` that meets the condition by `user.id`, and then filter out the `UserHasRole` containing `user` by `user`.

---

[Basic filters for lists](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#basic-filters-for-lists)